# ¿Cómo realizar una solicitud a la tienda Shopify desde la aplicación Shopify?

Tags: axios, shopify

Tengo una aplicación pública Shopify con Node y React, creada según este tutorial https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started.

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta con axios para extraer datos desde la tienda con este código, según lo indicado aquí https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/session-tokens/axios

```javascript
  const app = useAppBridge()
  const instance = axios.create();

  // Intercept all requests on this Axios instance
  instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    return getSessionToken(app) // requires a Shopify App Bridge instance
      .then((token) => {
        // Append your request headers with an authenticated token
        config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        return config;
      });
  });

  instance.get("/api/products")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response); // 500 (Internal Server Error) "No shop provided"
    });
```

Y me arroja un 500 (Internal Server Error) **"No shop provided"**